# Simplifying an expression with vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the vectors $u,v,w\in\mathbb{R}^3$, given by $u=(u_1,u_2,u_3)$, $v=(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ and $w=(w_1,w_2,w_3)$. I'm looking for a simplification for the following expression 
$$(\langle v,w\rangle u- \langle u,w\rangle v)\times w$$

rather with the term $\langle u,v\rangle $ showing up. I tried doing the calculations "by hand" but didn't help.

Hope someone here see something I missed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [vector triple product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product#Vector_triple_product) problem, assuming that $\langle x,y\rangle$ means the standard inner product, the dot product $x\cdot y$.

$\langle w,v\rangle u-\langle w,u\rangle v= w\times (u\times v)$.

So the original problem is $\left( w\times (u\times v) \right) \times w$.

Comment: Could you say what property did you use? Thank you.

Comment: Oh, dont bother. I read so fast that I skipped the link.